# Link $window variable to $scope and update it when itchange

Tags: angularjs

i have a controller:

```
myApp.controller('vistaPreviaCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 
    function ($scope, $window) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function (){
            $scope.my_var = $window.my_var; //once
        })
}]);
```

I want every change made in $window.my_var change in $scope.my_var too. There is a way?

Comment: You can use a watcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$window.my_var` is an object or array:

```
myApp.controller('vistaPreviaCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.my_var = $window.my_var;
}]);
```

`$scope.my_var` will point to the same object referenced by `$window.my_var`, so they are already  inherently "linked".

If `$window.my_var` is a primitive (e.g. number, string), you need to use a watch to update the local $scope's value.:

```
myApp.controller('vistaPreviaCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.$watch('$window.my_var', function (newVal) {
        $scope.my_var = newVal;
    });
}]);
```

I also recommend reading more about references and values in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/2943490.

Comment: Using and storing values outside the Angular life-cycle is not a good idea and will only lead to much frustration. If you are trying to share data it is best to use Services, Factories, or Providers.